Replaced dimmer with regular light switch and now the other light switch does not work
I have a set of overhead lights that were wired to both a dimmer and standard flip style switch. I needed to remove the dimmer and put a standard flip switch in its place. On the dimmer I removed, there was a black wire coming out and then two red wires that came out separately. I did some reading which I realize now I probably misunderstood, but I removed the dimmer and ended up connecting the black wire to the top terminal of the flip switch, and then the two red wires to the bottom terminal. Now the lights work with the switch I replaced, but not the other switch that previously could turn them on or off. What did I mess up here? I am at a bit of a loss.

you have a 3 way circuit/wiring, put in the 3 way switches and connect them properly

Here's hoping the OP took pictures before taking the wires off.

You've installed the wrong part, effectively shorting out the other switch.  You have three options:

Remove the new switch and replace it with the correct part.  You need a 3-way switch to replace the old 3-way dimmer.

Enable series switching by disconnecting one of the red wires and covering it with a wire nut and tape.  This would allow you to turn off the light from either switch.  However, both switches would have to be on to turn on the light.

Eliminate the other switch and splice its hot and traveller wires together.  This would leave only the one new switch and it would work normally.


The remaining concern:  The 2 wires that are connected to a single terminal have to be clamped rather than twisted.  Putting them both under a regular screw terminal is not allowed.
